# Passing composite value into procedure in mssql

Tags: sql-server, parameter-passing, composite, multiple-value

Is there a possibility in MSSQL to pass composite value into procedure for immediate executing or as prepared statement?

```
create type tt_p as table(i int, name varchar(200))
GO
create procedure p @t tt_p readonly, @prepared integer
as
-- procedure body
GO
```

Now I want to call something like this

```
execute p {(1,'name1'),(2,'name2')}, 1
```

Or is possible to prepare both values for php_odbc?

```
execute p ?, ?
```

I am not content with this solution, because drivers have problems with preparing commands which start with declare statement or combine insert/update/select/execute statements:

```
declare @t as tt_p
insert into @t values(1,'name1'),(2,'name2')
execute p @t, ?
```

Comment: then you would have to declare that parameter as varchar and write your logic inside stored procedure to convert that to a temp table or CTE

Comment: Good idea. I found some json to table conversions, but not pleased from existing solutions yet.

Comment: you may consider posting in your question on what you tried, didn't like or how you want so we can help you on that